Не работает Animation в unity
Нужно сделать покадровую 2d анимацию, использую компонент Animation,
добавляю спрайты, но анимация не работает,
даже при ручном перемещении ползунка в ручную спрайты не меняются.
Версия Unity: 2022.3.21f1
